# Date Subtraction within Select Statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am currently working on an MS Access database, and am having problem with date subtraction.

Essentially I am trying to create a target date for example:

Target Date = Deadline - Lead Time

i.e. the lead time could be 30 days, therefore the target date should be 30 days prior to the deadline.

The code I am trying to use is this:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo_DEALER_TASK ( Dlr_Number, Action_Id, Task_Id, Area_Id, 
Task_Deadline_Date, Responsible_Person_Id, Alternate_Person_Id, Priority, Comment, 
Suppress_Email, Dealer_Type ) "

strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT dbo_DEALER_ACTION.Dlr_Number, dbo_DEALER_ACTION.Action_Id, 
qryAllTasksToAdd.Task_Id, qryAllTasksToAdd.Area_Id, Deadline_Date - Deadline_adjustment 
AS 'Task_Deadline_Date', qryAllTasksToAdd.Person_Responsible_Id, 
qryAllTasksToAdd.Alternate_Responsible_Id, qryAllTasksToAdd.Priority, 
qryAllTasksToAdd.Comment, qryAllTasksToAdd.Suppress_Email, 
qryAllTasksToAdd.Applies_To_Dealer_Type "

strSQL = strSQL & "FROM dbo_DEALER_ACTION LEFT JOIN qryAllTasksToAdd ON 
(dbo_DEALER_ACTION.Dealer_Type = qryAllTasksToAdd.Applies_To_Dealer_Type) AND 
(dbo_DEALER_ACTION.Action_Id = qryAllTasksToAdd.Action_Id) "

strSQL = strSQL & WHERE (((qryAllTasksToAdd.Task_Id)=" & Me.Task_Id & ") AND 
((dbo_DEALER_ACTION.Date_Completed) Is Null));"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

When the VBA code executes the statement, everything is updated correctly, except for the Task_Deadline_Date field, which is being left blank.

What is really confusing me though is if I run this SQL statement standalone it is working as expected. After trying a number of different ideas I tried to replace "Deadline_Date - Deadline_adjustment AS 'Task_Deadline_Date'" with a string literal date and the statement then worked fine

Does anybody have any ideas what is going wrong?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: As an aside `DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL, dbFailOnerror` is always a good idea

Comment: Yeah it works within the query designer exactly as expected, but from the vba it populates all columns except the Task_Deadline_Date

Comment: Hi Everyone, I have just managed to fix the problem. As it stood this query was being performed in an "After_Update" subroutine, which occurred after a record was duplicated on the DB, all triggerred by one button. I split the functionality so it is now in two separate buttons (1 to duplicate the record, and a second to run the SQL query) and the code is now working as it should. I will accept HansUp's response (as I am now using his parameter code) but than kyou all for you time and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access' query designer, start with the version of your query which works and convert it to a parameter query.

```vb
WHERE
        qryAllTasksToAdd.Task_Id=[which_id]
    AND dbo_DEALER_ACTION.Date_Completed Is Null;
```

You can also add a `PARAMETERS` statement at the start of the query to inform the db engine about the data type of your parameter.  Examples ...

```vb
PARAMETERS which_id Text ( 255 );
PARAMETERS which_id Long;
```

Once you get that query working, save it and give it a name.  Then your VBA procedure can use that saved query, feed it the parameter value, and execute it.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("YourQuery")
qdf.Parameters("which_id").value = Me.Task_Id
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

This should be much easier than trying to recreate that SQL statement in VBA code each time you need to execute it.

Comment: Thanks for that, I did think about doing it this way but I couldn't figure out the parameters bit (i'm new to vba), i'll give it a go in the morning

Comment: OK.  The key point here is you *should* be able to use VBA to execute the same saved query which works correctly from the designer.  That could be easier for you; it's definitely easier for me than trying to diagnose the SQL built from your code.  :-)

Comment: Ok I tried this first thing, no joy. When calling the query from vba still no date, but if I run the query from designer mode (and type the task_id into the dialog box) it works like a charm. One thing to note though - this one does not give the same warning as above (i.e. Access set one field to Null due to a data conversion error).

Answer (score 1):

You have quoted the alias, you should not do that:

```
 Deadline_Date - Deadline_adjustment AS Task_Deadline_Date
```

Not

```
 Deadline_Date - Deadline_adjustment AS 'Task_Deadline_Date'
```

When you add the quotes, the name of the field is `'Task_Deadline_Date'`

Depending on the data type of your date field and whether or not you are using SQL Server, you may need to use DateAdd, for example:

```
DateAdd("d",-[Deadline_adjustment],[Deadline_Date])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think those quotes may have been a left-over of one of my attempts at fixing the problem, just tried it without the quotes and having the same issue =[

Comment: What do you get when you simplify? Say `SELECT Deadline_Date - Deadline_adjustment AS Task_Deadline_Date FROM nameofTable` ? I see dbo there, are you using SQL Server? If so, Access sees some SQL Server date types as strings.

Comment: Just to add to that, you may be able to subtract a value from a datetime data type but not from a date data type, if this is the case, try `DateAdd("d",-10,[ADate])`

Comment: I just ran the following: SELECT Deadline_Date-Deadline_adjustment AS Task_Deadline_Date FROM dbo_Dealer_Action LEFT JOIN qryAllTasks ON dbo_Dealer_Action.Action_Id = qryAllTasks.Action_Id; and it returns the date as expected

Comment: And there are no rows with an error? What is the data type of the field you are inserting to? Have you tried wrapping in CDate, just in case?

Comment: It is a Date/Time field and just tried with CDate with no joy. The really strange thing is if I take the query from the vba, get rid of quotes etc and run it as an sql query, it's working fine :/

Comment: What are you using for Me.Task_Id in the query design window? Are you sure it is the same in both cases? Do all the records update as expected except that the date does not work in VBA but it does work in the query design window?

Comment: Yeah all the records update as expected in the design window, and only the date does not work in VBA. Me.Task_Id is the same in both cases yes, when running this in the query window I have just been entering the one ID and it has been fine.

Comment: I cannot get this to fail without an error. I wonder if warnings has been set off on your computer at any stage? `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` would set them on again if it has.

Comment: For the most part, unless you find why a problem is occurring, you will be likely to be bitten by it again.

Comment: I have just tried to DoCmd.SetWarnings True - Placed it at the start of the so it was definitely on for the SQL, went through with a warning stating "Access set one field to Null due to a data type conversion error". I have just checked and Deadline_Date is a Date/Time field as is Task_Deadline_Date. Deadline_Adjustment is a Number field

Comment: I also just tried the DateAdd function, this causes the statement to fail with a runtime error 3464 (Data mismatch exception). I also tried this - CStr(DateAdd("d", -[Deadline_adjustment], [Deadline_Date]) As Task_Deadline_Date. Same error for both =[

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the data type of the column you are inserting in dbo_DEALER_TASK is not actually a datetime field.

> I tried to replace "Deadline_Date - Deadline_adjustment AS 'Task_Deadline_Date'" with a string literal date and the statement then worked fine

If you mean '02/20/2012' (as you would correctly use on SQL Server, for example) then this shouldn't work in Access and only will if your output column is a text (= varchar/char)) data type.  Date constants in Access are specified like #02/20/2012#

Please confirm the data type of Task_Deadline_Date in your output table.

Comment: I definitely used '01/01/2013' as the String literal. But Task_Deadline_Date is definitely a Date/Time field. I just tried the code with CStr(Deadline_Date-Deadline_adjustment) As Task_Deadline_Date and get the same warning as in my reply to Remou (i.e. Access set one field to null due to a data type conversion error)